# Can i use the same old Tracking code to Migrate UA to GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

i am currently trying to migrate my website which is using old UA Google Tag (gtag.js) to GA4.
i have created a new GA4 property and connected a new GA4 to UA Tag
My question is will i still be able to capture all the traffic with using the old gtag.js code snippet after 1st July 2023
Are there any other options for me to continue using Google Analytics UA (old JS snippet) without changing the gtag.js code on my html website?
i want to avoid changing my code base and cannot use Google Tag Manager
Thanks in advance
Kind regards,
Yash

[image: New Ga4 tag connected with Old UA Tag]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can keep using your old UA code and the migration that you've done is considered to be an MVP migration. It's good enough if you mostly use tracking for fun rather than to actually make consistent data-driven business-decisions.

Once you need it, you can switch to using GA4 properly, if ever.